# Traceback (most recent call last): ruby: No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, traceback

I'm following code from a book called: "RailsSpace: Building a social networking site with ruby on rails" by Michael Hartl. The book is available free for download here is the link so you can follow along with me: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ca98/3b5098cd5957dc1842bb4bf3175406624bca.pdf?_ga=2.121598472.1814901715.1569094472-1963651489.1569094472.

The code starts on page 70 asking me to enter this in my command prompt:

```
ruby script/generate model User
```

When I enter that code into the command prompt I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): ruby: No such file or directory --script/generate (LoadError).
```

The book was published around 2007 so its probably a little out of date with the commands I'm not sure. There maybe a more modern way of doing it, I'm not sure. I don't know if anything is deprecated or not. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're using a twelve year old book about Rails 1. It would have used Ruby 1.8 which was itself retired in 2013. You will be _much_ better off if you abandon everything you have done so far and restart completely from scratch with a book or tutorial about Rails 5 or Rails 6 using Ruby 2.4 or later. If you continue using this book you will be learning essentially zero transferable skills and will encounter so many roadblocks as to be comical. _No one_ can help you use Rails 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rails g model User` instead. The reason of this error is that this book use old rails syntax, you should try something newer for learning purposes, or install ruby and rails with versions same or above those in book.

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestion, here is a link to what I get when I try `rails g model User` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209276/yaml-syntax-error-occurred-while-parsing-c-users-vanessa-rails-space-config-dat

Comment: I just posted an answer on your other question. Also, keep in mind, if you are just learning Ruby on Rails, try to find a more recent book. Michael Hartl has another book called Ruby on Rails Tutorial. It was available to read online free, but I'm not sure if that is the case anymore. You can find out more at https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-6th-edition.