# YAML syntax error occurred while parsing C:/Users/Vanessa/rails_space/config/database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, yaml, config

When I enter this code into my command prompt:

```
  rails g model User
```

Here is what I get in the console:

```
  YAML syntax error occurred while parsing 
  C:/Users/Vanessa/rails_space/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML 
  must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: 
  (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at 
  line 7 column 1 (RuntimeError)
```

Here is the code from my config/database.yml file:

```
    # SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
   adapter: mysql
  database: rails_space_development
  username: root
  password: NothingToSeeHere
  host: localhost

  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, under your development key, for adapter, you have a spacing error. Try changing it to:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
```

You have one too many spaces before `adapter`.

YAML is very specific about spacing. As you've found out, even one extra space throws an error. And you have to make sure you use spaces, not tabs.

Comment: As an additional note, there are a lot of YAML validators online, as well as plugins for most editors which will validate YAML as it's written.

Comment: Hey thanks so much that solved my problem. It was a quick fix. Thanks man.